# Question about homological algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $m$ and $A$ a $G$-module of order $n$ with $(n, m) = 1$. From homological algebra, we know that $mH^{1}(G, A) = 0$ (in fact the 1 can be replaced by any integer $r \geq 1$). Does the $(n, m) = 1$ imply that $H^{1}(G, A) = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. Recall that an Abelian group $A$ is uniquely divisible by $m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ if for each $x\in A$ there is a unique $y\in A$ such that $x=my$. The following holds:

> If $G$ is a finite group of order $m$ and $A$ is a $G$-module uniquely
>   divisible by $m$ then $H^k(G,A)$ is trivial for all $k$.

In your example, since $(m,n)=1$, the map $x\mapsto mx$ is an injective endomorphism of $A$, so it must be an automorphism, which means that $A$ is uniquely divisible by $m$.

As a side note, you do not need to assume $(m,n)=1$ to get $mH^k(G,A)=0$ for any $k$.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned (entirely correctly) already, the answer is **yes**.  Here is a slightly different take on this:

If $A = A[n]$ is an $n$-torsion $G$-module, then even at the cocycle level one has 
$Z^k(G,A) = Z^k(G,A)[n]$ for all $k \geq 0$, hence certainly upon passage to cohomology one has $H^k(G,A) = H^k(G,A)[n]$ for all $k \geq 0$.  Thus for a finite group $G$ and an $n$-torsion $G$-module $A$, for all $k > 0$ the groups $H^k(G,A)$ are $\# G$-torsion and $n$-torsion, hence $\operatorname{gcd}(\#G,n)$-torsion.